# Firebase - Check if it's the first time signing in

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I need to check if the user is signing in for the first time, and initialize their account with extra properties (points, membership, accountCreationDate, etc) if true. My code currently only signs the user in. I'm following along with the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) (Step 5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

I decided to just go my own way with this:

```
googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}

private oAuthLogin(provider) {

  return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((credential) => {

    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`Users/${credential.user.uid}`);

    userRef.ref.get().then((doc) => {
      if(doc.exists){
        console.log('User exists!');
        this.updateUserData(credential.user);
      } else {
        console.log('User doesnt exist. Creating...');
        this.createUserData(credential.user);
      }
    })

  })

}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that @Ti Wang's answer is the best way (and should be marked as accepted).

However, if for some reason you don't get the `UserCredential` object (e.g. because you use some 3rd party login process), there's another way **without needing an extra call to firebase**:

The [`user`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object that you can get from [`firbase.auth().currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) contains a [`metadata`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#metadata) property that [offers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.UserMetadata):

```js
{
creationTime: 'utc string',
lastSignInTime: 'utc string'
}
```

When you sign up (ie login for the first time) **both strings are equal**.
So:

```js
if (
      firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.creationTime ===
      firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
    ) {
        // sign up
    } else {
        // login
    }
```

Comment: It can be used with `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` listener as well.

Comment: Is there a benefit to this answer, as opposed to `authDataResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the isNewUser field from [addtionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.AdditionalUserInfo) object.

Comment: The reference page doesn't provide an example on how to use it. Can you show me how?

Comment: SignInWithPopup returns a UserCredential object. You can check UserCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser attribute. If it's true, means the user is signing in for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but I came across this when searching for some answer.

When I login via Google I use this:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider)
```

This returns firebase.auth.UserCredential. Here there is a property called 'User'. Within this you can find the property additionalUserInfo -> isNewUser. When I login for the very first time (account not known at FireBase) the isNewUser is set to true. When I do another login with the same Google account this isNewUser is set to false.

If more infor is needed, let me know.